# Can not choose new date on jquery-ui-datepicker, automatic focus on previous picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

[Problem]

I have two empty textboxes (jquery-ui-datepicker).

When I clicks on textbox1, it shows calendar1, I chooses new date.

Then I clicks on textbox2, it shows calendar2, I chooses new date.

But when I clicks on new date on calendar2, textbox2 is still empty, calendar2 hides and calendar1 shows.

Again and again.

Is there anyone who has this problem? Please help me!

I can not upload my source code because of security. Sorry about my English. Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but we cannot help you without the source code. If there are security concerns, just create a copy of code to illustrate the issue. You can rename the variables and other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Can't predict what is the error unless the code is shown. However check the following working code to compare with yours and find out what's wrong.

```html
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker1"></p>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker2"></p>
```

Of course, add jQuery and jQuery UI css and javascript file.